# Can Static Members that Accept Variables Become Corrupt?

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, thread-safety

I'm having trouble forming this question, so I will try to state it a few ways so this doesn't end up repeating the usual discussions on static methods. This might be more of an architecture question.

If you have a static member on a static class that accepts variables passed in, is there any risk of a data collision / corruption if the operations are high use and long running? IE: data access classes accepting object graph types for persistence into a database.

For Example:

```
namespace MyApp.DAL.People
{

public static class Person
{
    public static void Insert(Entities.People.Person p)
    {
        // ADO.net code, try catch etc, execute to db, call other private method
        ....
        Helper(p);
    }

    private static void Helper(Entities.People.Person p)
    {
        // do work...

    }
}

}
```

If user "A" starts a `Person.Insert(myNewPerson)` call operation does that process finish in full before user "B" gets to use the static class and method to save his "person object" to the database.

Are the operations serial and asynchronous, essentially blocking for use of the static class?

Is this only an issue if the application (a developer) was attempting to use multiple threads in an application space?

Is everything running on a single thread unless you explicitly spin up another thread for an application?

*As a side note, this is my first post on SO - A special thanks to all you guys that take the time to post questions / answers - your time is appreciated!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two different threads call `Person.Insert` at the same time, they will both execute at the same time. Unless there's some explicit blocking in the method.

The data passed in the `p` parameter by thread `A` won't be accessible by thread `B`. Assuming, of course, that those two threads passed references to completely different object instances.

The calls are perfectly safe as long as nothing in the `Insert` method accesses anything at an outer scope. All method local variables, for example, will be different for the two threads. It's only when the method (or the methods it calls) starts accessing data at an outer scope when you begin to have problems.

Comment: @Richard: Note also that C# does not start new threads by itself. Even form events like button clicks wait until running methods terminate, before executing. You have to start new threads explicitly or by calling a method that does so (async stuff, BeginInvoke etc. methods).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Thank you, between yourself and Jim you have completely answered my question and set my mind at ease. I'm just starting to dig deeper into multi-threading and it's amazing how a little knowledge can start to make you think and question, well, that which isn't broken. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you have multi-threaded, unsynchronized writes to mutable data structures, then corruption is always a possibility. Static members are not special in this regard. If you want to lock access to them, you have to do so explicitly.

```
public static class Person {
    private readonly object syncLock = new object();

    public static void Insert(Person p) {
        lock(syncLock) {
            //...
        }
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Note: If you're not doing multithreaded access, then everything will run in serial anyway, by virtue of only using one thread.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I appreciate the input. Yes, this app is only single threaded. I couldn't find anything that simply said, "your app runs serial and on one thread" unless you do otherwise. (I'm sure this isn't technically absolute in all cases, but for the purposes of this arch question, these answers really help! Thanks.